# Rattle data view failing

Tags: r, rattle

I installed rattle 2.6.26

- load audit dataset
- click on Data > View

and got the following error

```
Error in appendLog("Use data.viewer() from Deducer.", view.cmd) : 
  object 'view.cmd' not found
```

I google if someone else had this problem and found the following posts but no solution:

[view.cmd](http://code.google.com/p/rattle/issues/detail?id=25)

Comment: which posts do you find, look like you forget to add link(s)?

Comment: I tried to find function `appendLog("Use data.viewer() from Deducer.", view.cmd)` in the src of the rattle package at http://code.google.com/p/rattle/source/browse/trunk/src/rattle.R?r=64 and in the Deducer package by downloading the package source.

Answer (score 0):

The author of the program suggested using his beta version in response to another problem so I tried it and that fixed this problem for me.  Of course, beta versions are a double edged sword.  The thing to do is to go into R and uninstall the rattle package.  Then reinstall the beta version using this command:

install.packages("rattle", repos="http://rattle.togaware.com", type="source")